# How do I create a child within a value in key value pair in pyrebase?

Tags: django, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I want my data in the database to look like this

```
>key
 -val1
 -val2
 -val3
 > val_key
   - val4.1
   - val4.2
```

I have added the values `val1, val2,val3` using the `set()` but I cannot seem to figure out a  way to create a key `val_key` as a child to the `key`. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

`db.child('key').child('val_key').set('val4.1')`